# Resampling from multiple strata using boot()

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I'm attempting to bootstrap a ZIP estimation while resampling from within specific populations. Each of the populations (clusters) are fundamentally different in some way, so I would like to proportionally represent them in the bootstrapping. The strata command will do that.

I sometimes encounter the following error:

Error in solve.default(as.matrix(fit$hessian)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.02001e-16

Here's a way to replicate the problem, and it should only take about a minute or so to run, depending on your computer:

```
#Load dependencies
library(AER)
library(boot)
library(pscl)
library(sampling)

#generate some fake data.q. Seed will be used to make it replicatable.
set.seed(1) 
x1<-rpois(1000,1)
set.seed(1)  
x2<-rnorm(1000,0,1)
set.seed(1)
e<-round(runif(1000,0,1)) #this should add some disruptions and prevent any multicolinearity.
pop<-rep(1:10,length.out=1000)  #there are 10 populations
y<-x1*abs(floor(x2*sqrt(pop)))+e  #the populations each impact the y variable somewhat differently
fake_data<-as.data.frame(cbind(y,x1,x2,pop))
fake_data$pop<-factor(pop)  #they are not actually simple scalars.

#Run zip proccess, confirm it works. I understand it's not a matching model.
system.time(zip<-zeroinfl(y ~ x1+x2+pop | x1+x2+pop, data=fake_data))

#storing estimates to speed up bootstrapping phase. General technique from http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/zipoisson.htm
count_hold<-as.data.frame(dput(coef(zip, "count")))
count_short<-c(count_hold[,1])
zero_hold<-as.data.frame(dput(coef(zip, "zero")))
zero_short<-c(zero_hold[,1])

#bootstrapping
f <- function(fake_data, i) {
  zip_boot<- zeroinfl(y ~ x1+x2+pop | x1+x2+pop, data=fake_data[i,], start=list(count=count_short, zero=zero_short))
  return(coef(zip_boot))
  } #defines function for R to repeat in bootstrapping phase. 

set.seed(1)  
system.time(res <- boot(fake_data, f, R =50, strata=fake_data$pop)) #adjust the number of cpus to match your computer.
```

There ought to be enough samples, considering that I have 900+ degrees of freedom, and at least 100 samples in each population to grab my resampling estimates from.

My questions:
1)What did I do that is causing this multicolinarity?

Comment: FYI: Turning off parallelization, I got this as the underlying error: `Error in solve.default(as.matrix(fit$hessian)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.09524e-35`.

Comment: So Peyton, you got me wondering if I programmed some sort of linear dependency in the program by accident. I increased the sample size from 1000 to 5000 and it went away, even with R=25. So this seems to imply that for some reason, 1000 samples happen to be correlated enough that zeroinfl() will not accept them, but it's not very obvious on visual inspection. I've also tried shrinking the number of strata to 5, and it works with 1k samples. Neither solution works for my real data set.

In my original sample, is there any way to make sure this won't happen?

Comment: I'm new to posting on Stack Exchange, so I'm not sure about etiquette or the proper procedure, but you might try narrowing the original question in light of what you've learned, or asking about the estimation in Cross Validated. I haven't had a chance to take a closer look at this, though it's interesting.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. Since the coding isn't the problem, it has something to do with the round/truncate commands confusing the optimization command during the regression. It's too nonlinar.